# Which package contains gstreamer-properties?

Tags: apt, package-management, gstreamer

Simple question:

```
$ gstreamer-properties
gstreamer-properties: command not found
```

What package do I need to install?

I've already tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

and

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Which package contains `gstreamer-properties`?

Answer (score 3):

It was part of `gnome-media` package until Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. However "gnome-media" has been removed from Debian repositories at [2015](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gnome-media) and afterward from Ubuntu.

[Search for the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gnome-media) : results nothing

Comment: So what can we do to set up our input devices?

Comment: Create a new question describing your problem... Someone might be able to help you :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590925/ubuntu-20-04-configure-input-output-devices